# Create a Image stack in PyTorch

Tags: numpy, pytorch

I have a `Bx3xHxW` image tensor in PyTorch and wish to create a `Bx3FxHxW` image stack of this image where `F=64`.

The image stack is formed by shifting the original image right. That is if the original image is to be shifted by 2 pixels to the right, the two left-most columns in new image will be `0` and the third-last column of the original image will become the last column of the new shifted image.

The image stack is formed by shifting right the original image `f` times where `f` varies from `0` to `F-1`.

How to achieve this in PyTorch in the most effecient manner using no or minimal number of `for` loops? A numpy code will also work as the two languages are quite compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Torch (as well as numpy) provides [`torch.roll`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.roll.html) function, by padding with zeros first, rolling and then slicing the result you can achieve your right shift.

Here's a numpy version:

```py
import numpy as np

X = np.random.rand(4,3,28,28)
Z = np.zeros((4,3,28,28))
XZ = np.concatenate([X,Z],axis=-1)

res = []
shift = 2
F = 28//shift
for i in range(0,F,shift):
    res.append(np.roll(XZ,i,-1)[:,:,:,:28])

res = np.concatenate(res,axis=1)
```

Here's a 1D example for better understanding:

```py
x = np.arange(10)
z = np.zeros(10)
xz = np.concatenate([x,z],axis=-1)

for i in range(0,10,2):
    print(np.roll(xz,i,-1)[:10])
```

```
[0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9.]
[0. 0. 0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 2. 3.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.